# Problems with a TFS 2010 build running indefinitely?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

A TFS build of mine that used to work started running indefinitely.

After queuing a build the build agent crashes. Here is the crash in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: TFSBuildServiceHost.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba20ec8
```

Has anyone else experienced a builds that never completes or the agent crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for this from

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534208/tfsbuildservicehost-exe-faulting

If I set Analyze Test Impact to FALSE in the build definition (under Process > Advanced), the build completes successfully.

EDIT: Same type of problem and solution can be found in
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/635483/get-impacted-tests-fails-with-operation-timed-out